# Why DOMContentLoaded handler can block first paint?

Tags: javascript, dom, domcontentloaded

*There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32656594/domcontentloaded-blocks-page-loading) that wasn't resolved.*

I've encountered a situation when handler that listens to DOMContentLoaded can block first paint.
Sometimes it blocks, sometimes it doesn't

I tried many times cmd + R to see it. Is there any explanation to this behaviuor?

Also I recordered a video to show this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EDZQ1nLCK2w&feature=youtu.be

1. When you see a blank page after reload then it means DOMContentLoaded blocked first paint
2. When you see the text "Some text" and then a blank page after reload it means DOMContentLoaded didn't block first paint

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    let i = 0;
    while (i++ < 1000000000) {
        continue;
    }
    document.getElementById('el').remove();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="el">Some text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because DOMContentLoaded is after all html has been printed and ready to be interacted with but before it has been rendered to screen.

Comment: I am just curious about what exactly you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. There is a bug in [Blink](https://www.chromium.org/blink) rendering engine that dispatches DOMContentLoaded event synchronously

```
// #blink/renderer/core/dom/document.cc
// #blink::Document::FinishedParsing

// FIXME: DOMContentLoaded is dispatched synchronously, but this should be
// dispatched in a queued task, see https://crbug.com/425790
if (document_timing_.DomContentLoadedEventStart().is_null())
  document_timing_.MarkDomContentLoadedEventStart();
DispatchEvent(*Event::CreateBubble(event_type_names::kDOMContentLoaded));
if (document_timing_.DomContentLoadedEventEnd().is_null())
  document_timing_.MarkDomContentLoadedEventEnd();
SetParsingState(kFinishedParsing);
```

** Why it sometimes was dispatched asynchronously I don't know. Now, on my side, it's always synchronous (probably there was one more bug at the time question was asked)

Answer (score 2):

It's a race condition.  Sometimes the document is already loaded/interactive before you add the listener.

You can see the difference by inspecting the document's readyState: [document.readyState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState).  Your code isn't running because sometimes the state is already `interactive` or `complete`, meaning that the `DOMContentLoaded` event has already fired before you've actually added the listener.

The way to handle it would be something like this:

```
function init() {
    let i = 0;
    while (i++ < 1000000000) {
        continue;
    }
    document.getElementById('el').remove();
}

if (document.readyState === 'loading') {
    // Document not yet loaded, so wait for it.
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);
} else {
    // Document is ready (interactive or complete), so call init immediately.
    init();
}
```